# Is it possible to animate a transformation that go from an object to another?

Tags: animation, modifiers, transforms

[image]

Hi!
I'm trying to do an animation where these glass plates will have to pass between the left form and the right form, so I was wondering if it is possible to animate directly this kind of transformation or to animate the curve modifiers that I used to create the left one. I search for a way to do so, but I didn't find it. If an extension is required, I don't mind to install it, I personally work with sensei format.
Thank you!

Comment: You could use shape keys, perhaps?

Comment: I agree, either using shapekeys, or if this is created by the use of modifiers, you could animate the properties on those. pressing I over a property sets a keyframe on it.

Comment: I'm using the curve modifiers+array modifiers and I just want to animate the curve one. I've tried to press I on some functionalities, it works when I do it on the visibility of the curve modifiers, but I have two new problem.First, the transition is non-existant (it's a plane and it bent suddenly). Next, the origin point is changing with the curve modifier, so the plane slide and I don't want it. I think I will try to manually bent it and insert shape keys, but it was easier to do it with modifiers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a pretty intuitive solution: I used shape keys on the paths I used to do my curve. So thank you all, you made me think about shape keys and I have now exactly what I wanted!